# CSS - How to place a div in the center of the browser without moving the other divs

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to design an index page, right now i did this code :
HTML :

```
<body>
            <header>
                <div class="Header_container">
                    <a href="me">
                        <img class="Logo" alt="Logo" src="CITYGAMEUR_LOGO.png">
                    </a>
                    <div class="Header_options">
                        <a class="Accueil" href="me">ACCUEIL</a>
                        <div class="DropDown">
                            <a class="Gaming" href="#">GAMING</a>
                            <div class="Contenu">
                                <a href="classement">CLASSEMENT</a>
                                <a href="ranks">RANKS</a>
                                <a href="events">EVENTS</a>
                                <a href="annonces">ANNONCES</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="DropDown">
                            <a class="Account" href="#">COMPTE</a>
                            <div class="Contenu">
                                <a href="parametres">PARAMÈTRES</a>
                                <a href="deconnexion">DÉCONNEXION</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <section>
                <div class="Body_container">
                    <div class="UserInfo">
                        <span class="HeyFonsi">HEY USERNAME</span>
                        <img class="UserAvatar" src="https://api.habbocity.me/avatar_image.php?user=WeiredAF&headonly=0&direction=2&head_direction=2&size=l" alt="UserAvatar">
                        <p class="IfMember Text">- Tu n'es pas un membre de l'organisation.</p>
                        <p class="UserRank Text">- Rank : Aucun.</p>
                        <p class="UserClassement Text">- Classement : Aucun.</p>
                        <p class="UserLevel Last Text">- Ton level gaming : Inconnu.</p>
            </div>


            <div class="OrganiInfo">
            <div class="Where">
                <span class="Text">Tu peux nous retrouver sur : </span>
                <center><a href="https://www.habbocity.me"><img class="CityLogo" alt="CITY" src="CITY.png"></a></center>
            </div>
            <div class="JoinOrgi">
                <div class="Header">
                    <img class="Locked" alt="locked" src="LOCKED.png">
                    <span class="Text">GAMEUR CITY</span>
                </div>
                <div class="Main">
                    <center><img class="Logo" src="CITYGAMEUR_LOGO.png" alt="Logo"></center>
                    <p class="Members">Membres : xx</p>
                    <a class="Options" href="https://www.habbocity.me">Aller au QG du Groupe</a>
                    <a class="Options" href="contact">Contacter les membres</a>
                    <button class="JoinOrgiButton">Demande d'adhésion</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="Footer_line"></div>
            <span class="Footer_copyright">CITY GAMEUR 2018.<br/>CMS fait de zéro par .</span>
        </footer>
    </section>
</body>
```

and the css :

```
/* HEADER */
header .Header_container {
    height: 75px;
    background: #242424;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #2e2e2e;
    padding: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
}
header .Logo{
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 63px;
    display: inline-block;
}
header .Logo:hover{
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
    transition: 1s ease;
}
header .Header_options{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    top: 15px;
}
header a{
    color: #e8e8e8;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 34px;
    padding: 40px;
}
header .DropDown{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
header .Contenu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    border-left: 7px solid #2e2e2e;
    border-right: 7px solid #2e2e2e;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #2e2e2e;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;

    transform: translateY(15px);
}
header .Contenu a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
header .DropDown:hover .Contenu{ 
    display: block;
}
header .Gaming{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: turquoise;
}
/* USERINFO */
section .UserInfo{
    margin: 0;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    border-right: 7px solid #2e2e2e;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width : 220px;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
}

section .UserInfo .HeyFonsi{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
section .UserInfo .Text{
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-bottom : 50px;
}
/* ORGANI INFO */
section .OrganiInfo{
    margin: 0;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    border-left: 7px solid #2e2e2e;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000000;
    width : 250px;

}
/* OPTIONS */

/* WHERE  */
section .Where{
    border-bottom: 7px solid #2e2e2e;
    padding: 25px;
}
section .Where .Text{
    font-size: 26px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
section .Where .CityLogo{
    display: block;
    transform: translateX(-10px);
}
/* JOIN ORGI */
section .JoinOrgi{
    padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
}
section .JoinOrgi .Header .Text{
    font-size: 26px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
section .JoinOrgi .Header .Locked{
    transform: translateY(5px);
}
section .JoinOrgi .Main .Logo{
    width: 113px;
    height: 118px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
section .JoinOrgi .Main .Members{
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
section .JoinOrgi .Main .Options{
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: #dadada;
}
section .JoinOrgi .Main .JoinOrgiButton{
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
footer{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3f3f3f;
}
footer .Footer_line{
    height: 7px;
    background: #2e2e2e;
}
footer .Footer_copyright{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 0 5px 30px black;
}
```

it gives something like this : 
[image]

I want to put a div between these two divs (the right one and the left one)(so in the center), i tried some methods but it always make the right div move. i dont want to use absolute position nor grids.
i want something like this (i did this with photoshop) :
[image]
Sorry for my bad english, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can float divs to get them next to eachother. See the example below:

```css
.left-div { float:left; width:10%; height:100px; background:green; }
.center-div {float:left; width:80%; height:100px; background:blue; }
.right-div { float:left; width:10%; height:100px; background:green; }
```

```html
<div class="left-div"></div>
<div class="center-div"></div>
<div class="right-div"></div>
```

I gave them heights to make sure that it appears and colors to make a difference between the divs. If you remove the height there is no content in the div so it won't show. This is also responsive: So if you change the with of your screen, they'll still fit into it and will become smaller.

When using floats make sure to clear. This can be done adding one div arround the three divs, and give it the class "clearfix" and use the css below:

```
.clearFix:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that by using display:flex and justify-content:space-between. Please check the following code and output.

```css
.Body_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.UserInfo {
    margin: 0;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    border-right: 7px solid #2e2e2e;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
}
.middle-content {
    width: 80%;
}
.OrganiInfo {
    margin: 0;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    border-left: 7px solid #2e2e2e;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000000;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Body_container">
                    <div class="UserInfo">
                        <span class="HeyFonsi">HEY USERNAME</span>
                        <img class="UserAvatar" src="https://api.habbocity.me/avatar_image.php?user=WeiredAF&amp;headonly=0&amp;direction=2&amp;head_direction=2&amp;size=l" alt="UserAvatar">
                        <p class="IfMember Text">- Tu n'es pas un membre de l'organisation.</p>
                        <p class="UserRank Text">- Rank : Aucun.</p>
                        <p class="UserClassement Text">- Classement : Aucun.</p>
                        <p class="UserLevel Last Text">- Ton level gaming : Inconnu.</p>
            </div>
  
            <div class="middle-content"><h3>What is Lorem Ipsum</h3>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                  
            <div class="OrganiInfo">
            <div class="Where">
                <span class="Text">Tu peux nous retrouver sur : </span>
                <center><a href="https://www.habbocity.me"><img class="CityLogo" alt="CITY" src="CITY.png"></a></center>
            </div>
            <div class="JoinOrgi">
                <div class="Header">
                    <img class="Locked" alt="locked" src="LOCKED.png">
                    <span class="Text">GAMEUR CITY</span>
                </div>
                <div class="Main">
                    <center><img class="Logo" src="CITYGAMEUR_LOGO.png" alt="Logo"></center>
                    <p class="Members">Membres : xx</p>
                    <a class="Options" href="https://www.habbocity.me">Aller au QG du Groupe</a>
                    <a class="Options" href="contact">Contacter les membres</a>
                    <button class="JoinOrgiButton">Demande d'adhésion</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: As I'm a big fan of grids (and this way of working out the floating divs): I would address that some IE versions won't support this. So keep that in mind when using this and not knowing the specifications. Modern browsers do support this, so if you don't support older IE version(s), this is a great solution.

Comment: I don't think there will be people who uses a a older version IE still because everything keeps updated in this 21st century technology world. Maybe some uneducated peoples only use old version. If only float works well then why they have created display options.

Comment: There are plenty of companys running old software that dont work on newer browsers. So they restrict their employees to work with those old browsers. But yes, I agree in most cases I won't support older IE versions too. But as I said: you don't know their requirements. Maybe they've to support them for a reason like I described above. Just adding in your post "works for modern browsers" would be my suggestion. Nothing more. ;)

Comment: Obviously there will arise a different requirements and here I'm not working for any client. I'm just giving my view on above question that it can also be done in different ways, that's all!